# ENBF to JavaCC difference between [] and {}

Tags: parsing, lexer, javacc, ebnf

I have the following 2 production rules in EBNF:

```
<CharLiteral> ::= ' " ' [ <Printable> ] ' " '
```

and

```
<StringLiteral> ::= ' " ' { <Printable> } ' " '
```

What is the difference between the two? [] imply 1 or more repetitions and {} imply 0 or more repetitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EBNF, `[X]` means 0 or 1 `X` and `{X}` means 0 or more `X`.

In JavaCC, `[X]` means 0 or 1 `X` for grammar productions; in regular expression productions, you should use `(X)?` instead. To express 0 or more `X` in JavaCC use `(X)*`.